# how do I print value in Text field from asyncstorage in react native?

Tags: arrays, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm new in this!

```
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("@MySuperStore:key", "I like to save it.");
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};

_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@MySuperStore:key");
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      return this.value;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error");
  }
};
```

How do I print stored values into the Text element?
Originally there was
console.log(value); instead of return value;

Do I need to call function _storeData to store data? Like _storeData() or what I have to do.

Comment: did you try putting the console log back?

Comment: Im using react native on android so I dont want to console.log.
I need to write the value from function into a text element.
Do I need to call this function to make it save into asyncstorage?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use **this** keyword on the return statement

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@MySuperStore:key");
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
      return value;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error");
  }
};
```

**_retrieveData** async function return callback method